# Python - re.findall returns unwanted result

Tags: python, regex, findall

```
re.findall("(100|[0-9][0-9]|[0-9])%", "89%")
```

This returns only result `[89]` and I need to return the whole 89%. Any ideas how to do it please?

Comment: Make it a string; `"89%"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trivial solution:

```
>>> re.findall("(100%|[0-9][0-9]%|[0-9]%)","89%")
['89%']
```

More beautiful solution:

```
>>> re.findall("(100%|[0-9]{1,2}%)","89%")
['89%']
```

The prettiest solution:

```
>>> re.findall("(?:100|[0-9]{1,2})%","89%")
['89%']
```

Answer (score 11):

```
>>> re.findall("(?:100|[0-9][0-9]|[0-9])%", "89%")
['89%']
```

When there are capture groups `findall` returns only the captured parts. Use `?:` to prevent the parentheses from being a capture group.

Comment: Would changing `100|[0-9][0-9]|[0-9]` to `\d{1,3}` change the intent of the pattern?

Answer (score 2):

Use an outer group, with the inner group a non-capturing group:

```
>>> re.findall("((?:100|[0-9][0-9]|[0-9])%)","89%")
['89%']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
re.findall("/d+/%","89%")
```

d+ gets a number, regardless of how long.