# re.findall gives different results than re.search with the same pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have  as str that I want to get the substring inside single quotes (`'`):

```
line = "This is a 'car' which has a 'person' in it!"
```

so I used:

```
name = re.findall("\'(.+?)\'", line)
print(name[0])
print(name[1])
```

> car
>   person

But when I try this approach:

```
pattern = re.compile("\'(.+?)\'")
matches = re.search(pattern, line)
print(matches.group(0))
print(matches.group(1))
# print(matches.group(2))  # <- this produces an error of course
```

> 'car'
>   car

So, my question is why the pattern behaves differently in each case? I know that the former returns "all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string" and the latter match objects which might explain some difference but I would expect with the same pattern same results (even in different format).

So, to make it more concrete:

1. In the first case with `findall` the pattern returns all substrings but in the latter case it only return the first substring.
2. In the latter case `matches.group(0)` (which corresponds to [the whole match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group) according to the documentation) is different than `matches.group(1)` (which correspond to the first parenthesized subgroup). Why is that?

`re.finditer("\'(.+?)\'", line)` returns match objects so it functions like `re.search`.

I know that there are similar question is SO like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42138765/python-re-findall-returning-different-results-from-re-search) or this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16045643/python-re-findall-returns-unwanted-result) but they don't seem to answer why (or at least I did not get it).

Comment: Do you understand at least that `re.search` only finds the first match?

Comment: As per [manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search): **Scan through string looking for the first location where the regular expression pattern produces a match**

Comment: re.group(0) refers to the overaching group.

Comment: Also `finditer` is supposed to be used in a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already read the docs and other answers, so I will give you a hands-on explanation

Let's first take this example from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group)

```
>>> m = re.match(r"(\w+) (\w+)", "Isaac Newton, physicist")
>>> m.group(0)       # The entire match
'Isaac Newton'
>>> m.group(1)       # The first parenthesized subgroup.
'Isaac'
>>> m.group(2)       # The second parenthesized subgroup.
'Newton'
>>> m.group(1, 2)    # Multiple arguments give us a tuple.
('Isaac', 'Newton')
```

If you go on [this website](https://regex101.com/) you will find the correspondence with the previous detections

[image: first example]

group(0) is taking the full match, group(1) and group(2) are respectively Group 1 and Group 2 in the picture. Because as said [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group) "Match.group([group1, ...])
Returns one or more subgroups of the match. If there is a single argument, the result is a single string; if there are multiple arguments, the result is a tuple with one item per argument. Without arguments, group1 defaults to zero (the whole match is returned)"

Now let's go back to your example

[image: second example]

As said by others with `re.search(pattern, line)` you will find ONLY the first occurrence of the pattern ["Scan through string looking for the first location where the regular expression pattern produces a match" as said [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search)] and following the previous logic you will now understand why `matches.group(0)` will output the full match and `matches.group(1)` the Group 1. And you will understand why `matches.group(2)` is giving you error [because as you can see from the screenshot there is not a group 2 for the first occurrence in this last example]

Answer (score 1):

1. `re.findall` returns **list** of matches (in this particular example, first groups of matches), while `re.search` returns
   only **first** leftmost match.

   As stated in python documentation ([`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall)):

   > Return **all** non-overlapping
   >   matches of pattern in string, **as a list of strings**. The string is
   >   scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. If
   >   one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of
   >   groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one
   >   group. Empty matches are included in the result.
2. `matches.group(0)` gives you **whole fragment** of string that matches your pattern, that's why it have quotes, while `matches.group(1)` gives you first **parenthesized** substring of matching fragment, that means it will not include quotes because they are outside of parentheses. Check [`Match.group()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group) docs for more information.